# execute multiple sql queries with fetch javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql, fetch

I am trying to figure out how to query multiple times with fetch and return data from SQL execution.

The solution doesn't have to be a Promise, I just want to execute multiple fetches and get the result each time before the next fetch is done.

I'm inside a function called by a click of a button, javascript/hmtl/python/flask/postgresql

```
     Promise.all([
        fetch("/query_village/village/1277"),
        fetch("/query_fathers/fathers/18")
        ]).then(values => {
        return Promise.all(values.map(r => r.json()));
    }).then(([village, fathers]) =>{
        console.log(village)
        console.log(fathers)
    })
```

I want the row 1277 of village and 18 of fathers.

What I get as a result is:

[image]

In the background, I have this code in python:

```
> @app.route("/query_village/<collection_village>/<code_id_village>")
> def query(collection_village, code_id_village):
>     data_village = Database.fetchall_where(collection_village, 'code_id', code_id_village, return_dict=True)
>     if data_village:
>         return data_village[0]
>     return {}
> 
> @app.route("/query_fathers/<collection_fathers>/<code_id_fathers>")
> def query(collection_faters, code_id_faters):
>     data_faters = Database.fetchall_where(collection_faters, 'code_id', code_id_faters, return_dict=True)
>     if data_faters:
>         return data_faters[0]
>     return {}
```

and in the database I have:

```
def fetchall_where(table: str, column: str, value: Any, return_dict=False) -> List:
    Database.CURSOR.execute(f"SELECT * FROM public.\"{table}\" WHERE \"{column}\"='{value}'")
    fetch_all = Database.CURSOR.fetchall()
    # Return as a dict 
    if return_dict:
        columns = [col[0] for col in Database.CURSOR.description]
        rows = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in fetch_all]
        return rows
    # Return as a list
    return fetch_all
```

Rest assured there is data in the village table inside the database. But it seems that the return of the village does not happen before the return of the fathers, as if the execution is overwriting the previous one.

I've added a few prints in the execution and I got this (I also tried with `fetchone()`):

```
here village
SELECT * FROM public."village" WHERE "code_id"='1277'
here fathers
SELECT * FROM public."fathers" WHERE "code_id"='18'
village (1277, 'some village', 2)
fathers None
```

As you can see it enters the route for village, execute the village, then enter with fathers, execute the fathers, then return the village with the value and now fathers is None...

Why isn't the print of the result of Village shown after the execution of the SQL statement?

Let me know if something is not clear in the example.

Comment: Most likely, the village query takes longer than the fathers query. Looking at your database code, it's probably because you're using `fetchall`. Fetchall returns every row. If  you just want a single row, why are you pulling every row per query? Use `.fetchone()` instead

Comment: oh, i'll try .fetchone() thanks for the suggestion :)